# How do I run the following bash code properly

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Hi I am new to programming and bash, i was given the following code and told to run it to install some required tools. I copy and pasted this to the terminal and i was not successful in installing. I also copy and pasted this in a `.sh` file and executed it in the terminal but I did not run anything. what am I doing wrong here

```
# Shell Scripting Reference:
# Link: https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/
function install_brew {
    # Brew Reference: https://brew.sh/
    # Homebrew Cheatsheet: https://devhints.io/homebrew
    echo "function::install_brew"
    if [[ ! $(command -v brew) ]]; then
        brew_url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh"
        echo "Homebrew is not installed , downloading it"
        $(command -v sh) -c "$(curl -fsSL $brew_url)" 
        else 
        echo "Homebrew is already installed!"
    fi
    echo $(command -v brew)
}
function install_jdk {
    echo "function::install_jdk"
    brew install scala
    brew install sbt
    echo "Finding Shells"
    currentShell=$(ps -p $$ -ocomm=)
    echo "Your current shell is: $currentShell"
    export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"
    export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openjdk/include"
    # Depending on the environment you use, you may need to update
    # your shell's boot config to persist changes
    if [[ $currentShell =~ "sh" ]]; then
        if [[ $(grep -Fxq 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"' ~/.bashrc) ]]; then 
            echo "Appending to PATH (sh) for OpenJDK installation"
            echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
            echo 'export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openjdk/include"' >> ~/.bashrc
            sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk
        else
            echo "OpenJDK setup already complete (SH)."
        fi
        else if [[ $currentShell =~ "zsh" ]]; then
            if [[ $(grep -Fxq 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"' ~/.zshrc) ]]; then 
                echo "Appending to PATH (zsh) for OpenJDK installation"
                echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
                echo 'export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openjdk/include"' >> ~/.zshrc
                sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk
            else 
                echo "OpenJDK setup already complete (ZSH)."
            fi
        fi
    fi 
    echo $($(command -v java) -version) && echo $($(command -v scala) -version)
}
function install_spark {
    # Reference: Scala Spark Setup
    # https://learnscalaspark.com/getting-started-intellij-scala-apache-spark
    # Reference: PySpark Setup
    # https://medium.com/@achilleus/get-started-with-pyspark-on-mac-using-an-ide-pycharm-b8cbad7d516f
    echo "function::install_spark"
    pkgs=("apache-spark" "python" "virtualenv")
    for i in "${pkgs[@]}"
    do
        brew install $i
    done
    # If you're creating a new virtualenv or even if you're using the one pathed on your computer, you can use pip to install pyspark
}
function install_optionals {
    echo "function::install_optionals"
    optionals=("terraform" "apache-flink")
    for i in "${optionals[@]}"
    do
        brew install $i
    done
}
#install_brew
#install_jdk
#install_spark
#install_optionals
```

Comment: The last 4 lines are commented out. You need to remove the `#`

Comment: BTW, note that `$(command -v java) -version` is both slower and buggier than just running `java -version`.

Comment: ...that's not the only antipattern here, which isn't surprising -- TLDP's ABS is somewhat infamous for teaching bad practices. As a place to start, you might consider https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete and [BashPitfalls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) for descriptions of what to avoid, the [BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) and [BashFAQ](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) as documentation better focused on good practices, and http://shellcheck.net/ (which can also be locally installed as a command-line tool) as a tool for catching common mistakes.

Comment: if nothing didnt help you from the comments above me.please validate that your sh script is executable.
you can run: chmod +x file_name.sh

Answer (score 2):

yes i agree with the above regarding un-commenting the last 4 lines. The only other thing I spotted was a missing shebang.

Make sure the file starts with:
#!/bin/bash

Then mark executable:
chmod +x scriptname.sh

Answer (score 0):

In your bash code, you've defined 4 functions, but you have not called the functions in your script.

You'll need to run each function. You can do so by un-commenting the last 4 lines of your script.

Comment: If you're adding an answer that only repeats something someone else said in a comment, while not strictly required it's good etiquette to mark that answer community-wiki (to not be getting reputation points for something that isn't original content).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Haven't posted on SO for >5 years. Unaware of the community-wiki feature. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Also, the commented solution does not explain *why* uncommenting the lines resolves the problem. As a trained educator, I submit that this is an important component of a good answer, and constitutes "original content"